# FTP is not connecting through Azure webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have deployed console application as webjobs on Azure which is getting data from ftp server but when run the console application on local it works fine but when deploy it on Azure it throws exception IO Exception while connecting to FTP server.

Comment: could you please share your code ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a webjob to get data from kudu via FTP, it worked fine on local but couldn't get data on the azure as same as you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {
        client.connect("url");
        client.login("username", "password");

        if (client.isConnected()) {
            // Obtain a list of filenames in the current working
            // directory. When no file found an empty array will
            // be returned.
            String[] names = client.listNames();
            for (String name : names) {
                System.out.println("Name = " + name);
            }

            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {
                // Check if FTPFile is a regular file
                if (ftpFile.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
                    System.out.printf("FTPFile: %s; %s%n",
                            ftpFile.getName(),
                            FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(ftpFile.getSize()));
                }
            }
        }
        client.logout();
    } `
```

Per my experience, it's due to the Kudu Network restriction. Webjob runs in its sandbox, the only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP `(80)` and HTTPS `(443)` TCP ports.

Applications can create a socket which can listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit they be on the same machine, will fail. Here is the [reference](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening).

If you still have questions , please let me know.